# meteor.js Template helpers as variable vs key+value

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteorite

```
Template.hello.loggedin = function() { return something }
```

vs.

```
Template.hello.helpers({
  'loggedin': function () { return something }
})
```

The former works (Template.hello.loggedin prints out the function in the console, adding parenthesis returns the something), the latter doesn't (gives undefined).

I thought these were equivalent??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent except in the case you found. There is an open issue on github about this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/886.

If you want to call `Template.hello.loggedin()` use the former.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
How would I use the latter?